# Можно ли обойтись без кеширования данных в файл?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Исходные данные:**

Старый проект на .NET Framework, БД на SQL Server, файлы хранятся в таблице в поле типа IMAGE. Файлы самого разного размера, от десятков байт, до сотен мегабайт. *Я знаю что это все устарело, но изменить структуру БД в данный момент возможности нет и, в обозримом будущем, не предвидится, увы.*

Новый проект - сервис, web api на ASP.NET Core, с той же БД в качестве источника данных.

**Задача:**

По запросу клиента получить файлы из БД и отдать в виде `FileStreamResult`.

---

Собственно сама задача не представляет сложностей, от слова совсем, но есть один затык, который хотелось бы решить красиво.

И так, текущее решение организовано следующим образом:

1. Чтобы не выгружать в память сервиса огромные файлы, работаю черед `SqlReader`, который позволяет создать поток к полю, содержащему контент файла.
2. Этот поток копируется во временный файл на диске, так как если задиспозить ридер, соединение закроется и данные будут недоступны, следовательно отдать этот поток напрямую в `FileStreamResult` нельзя.
3. Из временного файла отрывается поток, отдается в `FileStreamResult` и благополучно диспозится ядром ASP.NET Core по завершении передачи данных клиенту.
4. В фоне крутится сервис, который периодически чистит этот импровизированный кэш.

---

А теперь собственно вопрос: можно ли обойтись без копирования данных в файл, не загружая при этом весь контент файла в оперативку явно? Или может быть просто есть более красивое решение, которое я пропустил/не нашел?

Можно было бы вместо копирования в файл, отдать поток из `SqlReader` сразу в `FileStreamResult`, но тогда нужно обеспечить открытое соединение до конца передачи данных, следовательно `SqlReader` диспозить нельзя, а если ридер не диспозить, то как это сделать после завершения передачи данных, если ни одной ссылки на незакрытый `SqlReader` не осталось? Работа с БД организована через внутренние сервисы, которые инжектятся в контроллер, встроенными в ASP.NET Core, DI-средствами. Или все таки ридер можно убить "потом" (ну или он сам помрет, во что слабо верится) и я что-то не дочитал про ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант - наследник `FileStreamResult`, который принимает (и запоминает) в конструкторе `SqlReader`, переписывает `ExecuteResult` и закрывает `SqlReader` после вызова `base.ExecuteResult`.

Comment: блин, про возможность наследования я даже не подумал, надо попробовать

Comment: @rdorn У Вас, вероятно, и `SqlConnection` открыт. То есть наследнику надо отдавать ссылки на все, что должно быть закрыто после завершения чтения.

Comment: не, у ридера в настройках выставлено закрытие соединения при закрытии ридера, так что с этим все нормально.

Comment: Отличный вариант, компактный, аккуратный и скорость работы отличная. Спасибо.

Comment: @rdorn Рад был помочь.